# Notation question: what is $N_A$?

Tags: astrophysics, notation

I'm reading some literature on stellar opacity, and there is some notation that I don't understand. In particular, they write that the total density $\rho$ is related to the electron number density $n_e$ through $\rho = n_e \mu_e/N_A$, and related to the ion number density $n_I$ through $\rho = n_I \mu_I/N_A$. What are $\mu_e, \mu_I,$ and $N_A$ in these expressions? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Avogadro's constant**: approximately $6.022 \times 10^{23}\ \mathrm{mol}^{-1}$ (that is, somethings per mole).

Comment: Yes, Avogadro's number is the number of "particles" (atoms, molecules, nuclei, as appropriate) in a mole.  For example, 32 grams of O2 has one mole of O2 molecules.

Comment: Ah thank you! and then $\mu$ are the molar masses of the various particles. Why do astro papers use such strange units!

Comment: @David Using moles and molar masses is very common in many fields, especially chemistry. A mole is an macroscopic amount of a substance, and in practice it's more common to work with some number of moles of a substance than to work directly with a number of its microscopic constituents.

Comment: @David : Why is a mole a "strange unit"? Moles are very useful because they tend to correspond to a large-enough-to-be-visible-but-not-so-large-to-be-overwhelming amount when quantifying elementary constituents of matter.

Comment: yeah I suppose it's not strange - I'm just used to hbar = c = k_Boltzmann = 1 and I spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to figure out what N_A was haha.